# Why is parallel execution in multithreading much faster in OracleJDK when compared to OpenJDK?

Tags: multithreading, java, oraclejdk

I see in many instances that for some reason, OracleJDK seems to be doing much better when it comes to thread scheduling as compared to OpenJDK. It appears like the former is able to leverage multiple processor cores as compared to the latter. It would be great if someone can answer what is happening behind the scenes or is it merely that I am missing a point.

Thanks so much.